# scikit-surprise: python cannot find module even though pip lists it as installed

Tags: python, python-import, importerror

I am trying to use the scikit-surprise module to build a recommender system however I am having an error in getting it to compile.

I am receiving the ImportError: Cannot import name "Reader" error

My class is as follows

```
import pandas as pd
from surprise import Reader, Dataset

userReviewsFilePath ="UserReviewsFirst5000WithHeadings.csv"
ratings = pd.read_csv(userReviewsFilePath) # reading data in pandas df

ratings_dict = {'recipeID': list(ratings.recipeID),
                'rating': list(ratings.rating),
                'userID': list(ratings.userID)}
df = pd.DataFrame(ratings_dict)

reader = Reader(rating_scale=(1, 5))

data = Dataset.load_from_df(df[['recipeID', 'rating', 'userID']], reader)
```

pip show says that version 1.0.6 is installed

Comment: Have you tried properly installing/reinstall scikit-surprise? If you are a windows user try: `conda install -c conda-forge scikit-surprise`, more info can be found [here](https://pypi.org/project/scikit-surprise/)

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem come from the installation... I installed "surprise" and past your code and it worked:

```
import pandas as pd
from surprise import Reader, Dataset
print(Reader) # or just print(surprise) if you import surprise
```

out:

```
<class 'surprise.reader.Reader'>
```

Start by re-install surprise and tell us.

If you have more than one version of python, do:

```
which pip
```

to see if you installed surprise on the used version of python

Comment: Did you install surprise or scikit-surprise?

Comment: I installed surprise. I will check with scikit-surprise.

Comment: I uninstalled then reinstalled scikit-surprise and surprise on their own, and the error is still there. It also comes up when running the small code snippit you left at the top of your comment

Comment: Did you check on which version of python it is installed?

Comment: I ony have the python 3.6.7 installed on my computer

Comment: I'm on python 3.7.2. Try with this version. I will try with 3.6.7.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188904/discussion-between-adam-bellaiche-and-arjunlotay).

Comment: Hi @ArjunLotay, Were you able to solve the problem? 
I seem to be facing exactly same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's in `surprise.reader`: https://surprise.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reader.html

Your code should read:

```
from surprise.reader import Reader
from surprise.dataset import Dataset
```

*Edit*: I checked the instructions again which seem to contradict this, and give your original code as the correct example. https://surprise.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started.html#getting-started

So maybe they add their own shortcuts? Either way, it seems like this isn't the correct solution, sorry. (Unless it works, in which case their instructions might be out of date.)

Edit 2: They do alias it, so "from surprise import Reader" should indeed have worked: [https://github.com/NicolasHug/Surprise/blob/master/surprise/**init**.py#L19](https://github.com/NicolasHug/Surprise/blob/master/surprise/__init__.py#L19)

Comment: I changed it to "from surprise import reader, dataset" but I am still receiving the error "ImportError: Cannot import name 'reader' "

Comment: I made the changes to the code and received the ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'surprised.reader'; 'surprise' is not a package

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to do

`from surprise.reader import Reader`